# Create a global variable to store time from NSDate?

Tags: ios, xcode, global-variables, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I want to store the time during the run of the program to a global variable when it satisfy a if condition, So when new time is received it should be stored in the global variable,

Here in my if condition i want to check?

```
 NSDate* CurrentTime = [NSDate date];
```

// less than 30 seconds

```
if ([CurrentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:TimeStoredinglobalvariable] < 30.0f)
    {
        //do something
        //Reset the new time to
        TimeStoredinglobalvariable = CurrentTime;
    }
```

Is this way of implementing a if condition possible to implement my task? And how to get this global
thing done with NSdate ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an class method with a static variable:

.h

```
@interface YourClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSDate *storedTime;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "YourClass.h"

@interface YourClass()
    @property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSDate *storedTime;
@end

@implementation YourClass

static NSDate *_storedTime;

@synthesize storedTime;

- (NSDate *)storedTime {
    if (!_storedTime) {
        _storedTime = [NSDate date];
    }

    if ([_storedTime timeIntervalSinceNow] < -30.0f) {
        //Do you stuff...
        _storedTime = [NSDate date];
    }

    return _storedTime;
}

@end
```

Comment: @iTucker -Thank you for your valuable answer! But i need to expose it outside the class! So any way i can get it done? Please help me! :)

Comment: Thank you for ur answer! I used xcode with ARC, So ur code generates few errors in implementing, Can you please help me?

Comment: @iTucker , with ARC it says that interface can not be statically allocated

Comment: @synthesize storedTime;
 gives an strange error - ARC forbids synthesizing a property of an Objective-C with unspecified ownership or storage attribute! Guess need to define in .h file? I did the same thing! But y error? :(

Comment: Hmm, strange it gave no errors with me. I never used ARC, but after reading some other threads, I think the code should now be ok

Comment: @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *storedTime; works! U beauty! Thank you very much for helping me to establish my task! May all ur dreams come true! Ur really a good fellow who kept answering all my silly question and make this work! U deserve good future! Be happy!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the very basic idea of storing global variables -

In the .h file

```
extern NSDate myDate;
```

In the .m file

```
NSDate myDate = XXXX; //where XXXX is the value you need
```

Comment: As far as i know declaring global variables with extern is bit dangerous and not an acceptable way? Any different way?

Comment: When u try this way, as u mention, i get this error too... Interface type cannot be statically allocated.

Comment: @sam from what I know, people do declare global NSString's with extern

Comment: And you allocate the NSDate in the init method, not outside like you would with an NSString

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer- Can you please show it in a piece of code? Thank you!